# What is the right way to do such import

Tags: python, flask, python-import

So this is my current folder structure

```
└── Main folder/
    ├── subfolder/
    │   ├── subfolder_function.py
    │   └── subfolder_function2.py
    └── main.py
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCv0P.png)

and these are the contents of each file

**subfolder_function2.py**

```
def subfolder_function2():
    print("Hey I'm subfolder_function2.py")
```

**subfolder_function.py**

```
from subfolder_function2 import subfolder_function2

def my_function_from_subfolderfunc2():
    subfolder_function2()
```

**main.py**

```
from subfolder.subfolder_function import my_function_from_subfolderfunc2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(my_function_from_subfolderfunc2()))
```

Why do I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\R24\Main folder\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subfolder.subfolder_function import my_function_from_subfolderfunc2
  File "C:\R24\Main folder\subfolder_function.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subfolder_function2 import subfolder_function2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subfolder_function2'
```

What is the right way to access the function from subfolder_function2.py?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a relative import in `subfolder_function.py` to specify you want the import to be from the same directory. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) for more information on relative imports

#### subfolder_function.py

```
from .subfolder_function2 import subfolder_function2

...
```